# keyboard shortcut customizing in visual studio 2013

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, keyboard

Basically I want to Add a short cut key to write my Sign and Current Data + time on the Comment code to see in future when and by whom the code was changed ! I searched on net and i found the option for open the KeyBinding.json file either to Open from Tools > Modify keyboard short cuts or File > Preference > KeyBoard Short cut .. 
But I am not having either of the Option available in my menu or submenu .

Comment: KeyBinding.json is for Visual Studio Code, not for Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to create such command and assign a shortcut to it:

```
Sub Run(DTE As DTE2, package As Package) Implements ICommand.Run
    Dim textSelection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
    textSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection(), EnvDTE.TextSelection)
    textSelection.Text = "My sign " + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + 
        System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for Visual Studio that enables the use of macros in the Visual Studio IDE

[Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)

It has certain  handy features like following

- Record and playback active document operations and Visual Studio IDE
  commands
- Playback multiple times
- Manage and persist macros with a Macro Explorer
- Assign keyboard bindings to any macro
- Macros recorded as JavaScript files that call VS DTE APIs
- Macro editing in Visual Studio with DTE IntelliSense
- Stop playback
- Sample macros

However from **Menu>Tools>Macros>Macro Explorer** you can record your custom macros and also between lots of predefined macros you can find **Insert Date & Time** or **Insert Date** macro as per your requirement.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!