# How to define custom Keyboard shortcuts to insert snippet in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I am using Visual studio 2015 and was wondering if there is a way I can create a custom set of snippet or shortcuts which will insert something like below when I hit it.

`function(){}` or

`describe('',function(){});` etc.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260751/keyboard-shortcut-customizing-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 2):

It's easy ....

Open visual studio, copy and paste this code in new text file and save the file with snippet extension( function.snippet) in C:\Users\yourname\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>function</Title>
            <Shortcut>fun</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for create manual function loop</Description>
            <Author>Rajput</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>

            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>

            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[
            function(){}
            ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

you can also type anything like 
`describe('',function(){});`
 after[CDATA[ (in this place function(){}).

Now go  to tools > code snippet manager>Add ( locate the function snippet) that would be added. now type shortcut fun and hit enter. now you can see snippet is working fine.[image: image for adding snippet in VS]