# How to insert date and time in code in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, datetime, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to insert the date and time in my code, specifically in comments. So for example I want to type in...

// ??? Verify the following code works @*==>insert date and time here<==*

I don't care how, code snippet, keyboard shortcut, AutoHotkey, something else. Any recommendations?

FYI the ??? is for code searches to remind me to do something. Think of it as a bookmark.

I use C# but I guess if you have a solution it would work for all flavors of Visual Studio.

Comment: As a side note, you can use `//TODO:`-comments to create a list of stuff you need to do. Access it with `View`->`Task List`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260751/keyboard-shortcut-customizing-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: As a reply to Cody Gray, there is an extension for Visual Studio that enables the use of macros in the Visual Studio IDE

[Link] (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)
from **Menu>Tools>Macros>Macro Explorer** you can record your custom macros and also between lots of predefined macros you can find **Insert Date & Time** or **Insert Date** macro as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

in AutoHotkey:
(you can change the exe name/hotkey (currently ctrl+alt+t)/text as required)

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe wdExpress.exe
^!t::
FormatTime, vDate, , HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy
vOutput := "// ??? Verify the following code works @" . vDate
SendInput {Raw}%vOutput%
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Thank you. Autohotkey is almost an unknown language to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Notepad to achieve this. I've got a macro on a multi button mouse that opens Notepad, uses "F5" to input the date and time, copies it, then alt tabs back to visual studio and pastes it in.  It's a bit of a janky workaround, especially considering it doesn't always work unless the application frame host task has been ended, which seems to affect the timing of the mouse macro working. (I use Windows 10)
So I created a small .bat file to end application frame host when i run it, which i run, when i know i'm going to want to use the macro to insert the date and time in visual studio.  All in all, it works, but it's much jankier than i would like for it to be.  I'm of the opinion the developers of Visual Studio should put in a nice, simple option to insert the current date and time, like good old notepad does.  It would make things so much simpler.
You could also just have normal notepad open and alt tab over to it yourself, press F5, then alt tab back and paste, but that's a lot of extra key presses.  My method was the best solution I've found, although I haven't tried the AutoHotkey thing the only other answer here talks about.