# What happened to the VSDatetimeInserter for VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017

What happened to the VSDatetimeInserter for VS 2017? It was an extension for VS 2015 from WarNov. It was very handy for noting the date in a code file in the VS IDE. I could not find a built in solution.

Comment: `What happened to the VSDatetimeInserter for VS 2017?` - it never existed. [Works with: 2013, 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WarNov.VSDateTimeInserter).

Comment: As an alternative see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260751/keyboard-shortcut-customizing-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: I have downloaded Visual Commander and created a macro based on your code. Thanks

Comment: Do you resolve the issue by the code. if so, could you please post a reply and mark it as answer, it will be beneficial to other communities who have the similar issue.

Comment: This answer solved my issue, but where I and mark it as answered, like in MSDN,

Comment: you can post your solution and mark it as answer.

Answer (score -2):

What happened to the VSDateTimeInserter for VS 2017, is that at the time of your question, it didin't existed. It was only available for VS2013 and VS2015. Today nevertheless, the author of that tool, being me, have upgraded the addin for Visual Studio 2017. You can find the new version in the Visual Studio Gallery. Published [here](http://warnov.com/@VSDateTimeInserter2017)

If you are curious about how this was done, I have open sourced it. Find it on my [Github](http://warnov.com/@VSDateTimeInserter2017Repo)

Regards!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15838026)

Comment: The user is asking for a tool. Basically is asking where to find it. I'm giving him the answer. How would it be supposed to answer that question without using a link? Did you at least read well the question? "it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference" that is just what I did. Anyway, I have edited the answer to fit the robotic logic you are using to review it.